# Override Paste Into TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I want to override the paste function when in a specific textbox. When text is pasted into that textbox, I want it to execute the following:

```
AddressTextBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText().Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

(Changing from multiline to single)

How can I do this?

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446233/hook-on-default-paste-event-of-winforms-textbox-control

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's possible, you can intercept the low-level Windows message that the native `TextBox` control gets that tells it to paste from the clipboard.  The `WM_PASTE` message.  Generated both when you press Ctrl+V with the keyboard or use the context menu's Paste command.  You catch it by overriding the control's `WndProc()` method, performing the paste as desired and *not* pass it on to the base class.

Add a new class to your project and copy/paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the existing one.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyTextBox : TextBox {
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        // Trap WM_PASTE:
        if (m.Msg == 0x302 && Clipboard.ContainsText()) {
            this.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText().Replace('\n', ' ');
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I put this in the Program.cs or the Form1.cs? And do I need to call it some how? because it isn't working

Comment: You put this in a separate class.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.

Answer (score 5):

To intercept messages in textbox control, derive a class from TexBox and
implement

```
class MyTB : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {

            case 0x302: //WM_PASTE
                {
                    AddressTextBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText().Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
                    break;
                }

        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
```

suggested [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/249589-intercept-paste-textbox-control)

Comment: If I put this in my Form1.cs I get the following error: Error Cannot access a non-static member of outer type via nested type and If I put into Program.cs It says that AddressTextBox does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Add a new class through project->Add New Item - class name it `MyTb`. When you will build the project the MyTB will appear in toolbox. You can place it on your Form.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, however your code didn't do the trick or I didn't use it correctly. Thanks anyways!