# WinProc and overriding the on paste method

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I was trying to override the onpaste method of the winform textbox using the following method:

[Override Paste Into TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852509/override-paste-into-textbox)

When the paste happens I don't want windows to handle it I want my code to. So I did the following:

```
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            var evt = Pasted;
            if (evt != null)
            {
                evt(this, new ClipboardEventArgs(Clipboard.GetText()));
            }
        }
        else
        {

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

Is this a safe way to get win32 code to not handle the paste or  is there some case I am not seeing?

Comment: Looks like you have not even tried it yet?

Comment: I have tried it, but just wondering if there is anything wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use this pattern to define a Pasted event:

```
public event ClipboardEventHandler Pasted;

protected virtual void OnPasted(ClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (Pasted != null)
        Pasted(this, e);
}
```

Then you call `OnPasted` instead of calling the event directly so derived classes can control the functionality.