# C# Form Application Getting a ClipboardFormatListener to only receive messages when a user pastes content

Tags: c#

I am working on a project that tracks how often a user has to copy and past data is so if a user is constantly just pasting from one form to another we can automate parts so forms auto-fill. This is being used in a corporate call center for the the quality assurance people. The Form does a bunch of other stuff but that its not really important for the question.

As it stands the form application uses a keyboard hook to catch when a user does control+v. When it catches the control+v combo it grabs the contents of the clipboard and sends it off to the processing part of the program. This all works well and good, but it can not pick up when a user does a right click copy/paste I have to go a different route for that.

In order to try and catch when a user uses the right click copy/paste message I figured it would be just as easy to listen to the clipboard for changes. I accomplished this with `AddClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle);` and with a override for the WndProc method like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
        {
            IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();      // Clipboard's data.
            uint processID = 0;
            IntPtr ForeGroundWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(ForeGroundWindowHandle, out processID);

            if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                string text = (string)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
                ClipboardEventQueue.Enqueue(new ClipboardDataStorage(text, Convert.ToInt32(processID)));
                LogWrite(text); 
            }
            else if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                Bitmap image = (Bitmap)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                ClipboardEventQueue.Enqueue(new ClipboardDataStorage("Clipboard copied an image", Convert.ToInt32(processID)));
                LogWrite("Clipboard copied an image");
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is the the WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message is only sent when the user copies to the clipboard. And I only care about what they actually paste. Is there a way to get a message when the users pastes something or am I going to have to use a mouse hook to accomplish this by tracking right clicks?

Comment: Try looking at WM_PASTE

Comment: Yea I saw that. But I can't figure out how to catch it. I have seen stuff about listening on specific windows but I want to catch it system wide. And of course if I change 'm.Msg == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE' to 'm.Msg == WM_PASTE' it tells me that WM_PASTE doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Isn't WndProc per window anyway? You can always define WM_PASTE yourself, it's a windows constant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852509/override-paste-into-textbox

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I forgot to define WM_PASTE. Also it captures when they paste into any window not just into my application.

Comment: Never mind. It looked like it was working but I was mistaken. It wont catch pastes into other applications which is what i need it to do. Is there a way to make a hook like a mouse or keyboard hook that is a windows hook and gets the WM_PASTE message?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to catch paste from other application into yours. To catch paste from your application into others, you could look at WM_RENDERFORMAT, which is called every time an application retrieves the data that is on the clipboard.

Comment: Nope not from my application to other. I want to catch when when any paste is done at all. So if they open a web page in chrome and copy a street address and then paste that into some other program I want to catch that paste as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to catch when any paste is done at all. So if they open a
>   web page in chrome and copy a street address, and then paste that into
>   some other program, I want to catch that paste as well.

Unfortunately, the clipboard doesn't quite allow this kind of functionality. There are two main events that the clipboard is based on - advertising, and requesting. Let's say we have applications 'X' and 'Y' running. All other running applications can see when X advertises new data available on the clipboard. The WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message goes to every application. But when Y requests that data, only X knows about it. The WM_RENDERFORMAT message goes straight from X to Y.

As a very hacky workaround, you could listen for the advertisements. Whenever someone advertises new data, you request all of it from them. Then, you take control of the clipboard, and advertise the data again. This way, you steal ownership of the data, so you can work out when anyone is requesting from the clipboard. Follow the [tutorial here](http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/monitor-clipboard-in-c/) to set your window up as a clipboard viewer. In their WndProc loop, try this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    ...
    if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
    {
        IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        ClipBoard.SetDataObject(iData);
    }
    if (m.Msg == WM_RENDERFORMAT)
        Console.WriteLine("Clipboard data requested");
}
```

Comment: Any idea how one would go about doing something like this?

Comment: Updated answer to show a possible solution. Disclaimer - I haven't tried it yet...

Comment: Same issue as the original code i had for it. It gets when things are copied to the clipboard but not  when something is pasted from the clipboard

Comment: THe idea is that you now own the data, so you can see WM_RENDERFORMAT events

Comment: Alright. Thanks. It looks like what I was looking for (and what you are talking about doing) is called delayed rendering. I am working on implementing it and will update the post with a solution if this pans out.